# How to revoke access to IOS apps from enterprise account with older versions. Not New versions

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, apple-profile-manager

I have released the app with older version that are not having the force push update feature.

Due to this the new version apps can be forced to update and pushed with analytics feature.

The older version apps are not having the analytics and force push, hence few of the users are still using the app without knowing that they have to update the new app. This is from enterprise account not Appstore.

1. How can I make the users force stop using the old app and make them move to new (there are some few hundreds so tracking on server side is bit difficult).
2. If i revoke the cert then the new app users also will have issue now to use the app. No good idea to stop the new users who have migrated.
3. The push notification is send and also an article inside app to inform them but not all have migrated as seen.
4. List item

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your only "good" option to stop those old version is to revoke the certificate. Because the old apps have no method to check for updates or change functionality, the only way to stop old users would be to either revoke the certificate, or change the server in a way that breaks the old version.

If it were me, I would build a new version of the app with a new certificate and roll it out today (or as soon as possible), then force all users who have the force update functionality to get onto a new version with a new certificate.  Give it a few weeks for users to ensure the app gets updated when possible. After you give time for as many users as possible to update, I would revoke the old cert.  Any old versions of the app will cease to work.  You'll want to try to communicate with your users, because the experience for the end user is not good (the app will appear to launch and immediately crash).

You could do something similar if your app does any server side downloads on launch.  You could return corrupt data on the existing backend calls, which would cause earlier versions of the app to crash or misbehave. New versions of the app could either handle the new data, or make a call to a new backend URL. This isn't ideal, and is similar to the above, so I would recommend the certificate revocation above.

You say this is an enterprise distribution - I'm assuming you aren't managing these devices with an MDM system.  If you were, you could simply use it to force a new version onto the managed devices.

Comment: I am not using MDM , your solution for revoking the cert seems agreeable as I thought this earlier however this will loose the earlier users as my current situation is they are not even knowing that there is new update due to no update feature in their app.